# Arithmetic in finite fields with different bases

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography, change-of-basis

For what kind of operations are the normal bases better in cryptography? And for which operations are the polynomial bases better?

Comment: Presumably this is about fields of size $2^n$ such that $n$ is relatively large (large enough that using look-up table of discrete logarithms is not feasible)? I'm not an expert on this. My impression is that multiplication is reasonably fast with both, but often normal bases are better. The catch is that the speed difference depends on $n$ in an unpredictable manner. The root cause for that is that so called optimal normal bases only exist for certain values of $n$. In general the level of suboptimality varies randomly, and at some point a polynomial basis becomes better (not 100% sure).

Comment: (cont'd) division is a pain with both. Can't comment much as my coding experience is on the side of small fields, where those LUTs solve all the hard problems. Of course, Frobenius automorphism is always faster using a normal basis. I don't know how much  typical crypto primitives are effected by my listed observations (which is why I won't post an answer).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm talking about binary fields. I read about polynomial basis and normal basis and that some operations are more optimized in normal bases (for example, the square of an element) and others (e.g., multiplication) are more optimized with respect to polynomial basis. But this is not really clear to me. For example, in the case of multiplication of elements, using an optimal normal basis, when it exists, is better then using a polynomial basis? For the inverse, which one is preferred? 
I would like to have more clarity about it...

Comment: I suggest to read carefully the chapter 2 of the valuable book [Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387952734). Maybe you find it useful for your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a normal basis for $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$, $1, \alpha, \alpha^{q}, \ldots, \alpha^{q^{n-1}}$, then you can represent any element as a vector as follows:
$$x = a_{0} + a_{1}\alpha + \cdots + a_{i}\alpha^{q^{i}} + \cdots + a_{n-1}\alpha^{q^{n-1}} = (a_{0}, a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n-1}).$$
Now if you raise everything to the $q$ power, you obtain
$$x^{q} = a_{n-1} + a_{0}\alpha + a_{1}\alpha^{2} + \cdots + a_{i-1}\alpha^{q^{i}} + \cdots + a_{n-2}\alpha^{q^{n-1}} = (a_{n-1}, a_{0}, a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n-2}).$$

Now, most commonly (in computer science applications) you are going to be working in a field with $q=2$. Also, there are many computational algorithms that make use of repeated squaring. So you can square a field element using this representation by simply performing a cyclic shift of the vector coefficients.

(Note that none of this is specific to cryptography, just for general computation with finite fields.)